# UPC allocating dynamic array and sorting

Tags: c, sorting, memory-management, parallel-processing, upc

I try to read floats from a file and then sort them. Sort must be paralell UPC. That's current code:

```
#include <upc_relaxed.h>
#include <upc_collective.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int lt_int( shared void *x, shared void *y ) {
  int x_val = *(shared int *)x, 
    y_val = *(shared int *)y;
  return x_val > y_val ? -1 : x_val < y_val ? 1 : 0;
}

shared int size=0;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {


  FILE *f;
  int i=0;
  if (MYTHREAD == 0) {
    f = fopen ("dane.dat", "r");
    while (feof(f) == 0) {        
      fscanf (f, "%f\n");                
      ++size;    
    }
    fclose(f);
  }

  upc_barrier;

  /* allocation goes wrong! */
  shared [] float *array = upc_all_alloc(size, sizeof(float));
  /* printf("%d\n",sizeof(array)); // it returns 8! */ 

  upc_barrier;

  if (MYTHREAD == 0) {
    f = fopen ("dane.dat", "r");
    i=0;   
    while (feof(f) == 0) {
      printf("%d\n", i);
      /* segmentation fault! */
      fscanf (f, "%f\n", &array[i]);    
      printf("%f\n", array[i]);            
      i++;    
    }
    fclose(f);
  }

  upc_barrier;
  upc_all_sort( array, sizeof(float), size/THREADS, size, lt_int, UPC_IN_ALLSYNC);
  upc_barrier;  

  if (MYTHREAD == 0) {
    for (i = 0; i<=atoi(argv[1]) ; ++i) {
      printf("%f\n", array[atoi(argv[1]) + (size/atoi(argv[1]))]);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And I don't know what am I doing wrong. I get segmentation fault, becouse allocation of memory goes wrong. Can you help me?

Comment: You need to allocate more than *one* float's worth of space, don't you? Why don't you try allocating `sizeof(float)*THREADS` bytes instead.

Comment: I tried (I tried many things). sizeof(array) returns 8 again, and there is seqmentation fault again:(.

Answer (score 1):

This call is wrong:

```
fscanf (f, "%f\n");
```

Also your object `array` is a pointer to `float`. It is normal `sizeof array` will return the size of the pointer type (8 in your implementation) and not the size of the array object you allocated. You should check the return value of `upc_all_alloc` to verify there was no error during allocation (if the return value `== NULL`, the allocation failed).

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, now I'm looking for way to count number of floats in my file... I found I get 8 + (10 * lines number)...